# Highlight Taxonomy Term

Tags: 8, search

I'm working in Drupal 8 and am using `Search Api` for searching my website. I'm using the build in Highlight function and it works great on the title and on the body text. But I can't seem to get it to work for `Taxonomy Terms` in a `Entity Reference Field`.

I enabled the `Index hierarchy` processor to search the Taxonomy Term Reference. But this didn't help.

Is this possible and what are the settings I should use to get this to work?

Thanks in advance